# Drag and Drop between two D3 trees

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, tree

I want to drag and drop nodes in a one D3 tree to another in the same page. I cant find any tryout in the web. What would be the best possible way of doing it.

1. Two trees in two SVGs in a one container.
2. Both trees in a one SVG.
3. Two trees in two SVGs in a another parent SVG.

Comment: what about two trees one SVG ? Have an attribute on the dataset to say which tree they belong to (example treeA, treeB) and when you drag from one tree to the other (from treeA to treeB) just change the attribute value

Comment: Thanks @thatOneGuy. I'll try it out. Do u know any link where I can find a similar kind of implementation with an example code.

Comment: don't think I have seen any im afraid, shouldn't be too difficult. Ill see if i can get something together

Comment: @thatOneGuy i've able to do it using two trees one SVG. Thanks again for the tip.

Comment: no problem glad i could help